# Is this homebrew Gloves of the Fire Fist magic item balanced as an uncommon item?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, balance, homebrew

Just now I homebrewed the following item and gave it to a player:

> ### Gloves of the Fire Fist
>
> *Wondrous item, uncommon (requires attunement)*
>
> While wearing the gloves, once per day the wearer can cast *burning hands* without spending a spell slot.
>
> While wearing the gloves, the wearer can spend spell slots to cast *burning hands*, even if they do not have the spell prepared.
>
> While wearing the gloves, if the wearer casts *burning hands* naturally (by having the spell prepared), the gloves add 1d6 damage.

Does this seem balanced at uncommon tier?  What similar uncommon-tier items should I compare it to?

Comment: Consider specifying what type of damage the gloves add (the obvious assumption is Fire, but it's good to be clear about these things)

Comment: I’d also say explicitly it uses the casters' save DC, or, as it also can be used by non-casters, set a fixed one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This fits Uncommon

A comparative item is the *circlet of blasting*

> **CIRCLET OF BLASTING**
> *Wondrous item, uncommon*
> While wearing this circlet, you can use an action to cast the scorching ray spell with it. When you make the spell's attacks, you do so with an attack bonus of +5. The circlet can't be used this way again until the next dawn.

This casts a higher level spell that deals 6d6 fire once per day, *does not require attunement*, and is Uncommon. Your item is superior in presumably allowing the caster to use their own spell save DC which scales better, but in the levels where this spell is worthwhile — especially if you require attunement — that shouldn't matter much. Your item also provides "always prepared" access, but overall I think is clearly weaker than this. Attunement is a huge downside, and the damage is at best half this. So your item should be no more rare than Uncommon.

The only alternative would be Common. There are very few common items in the core rules, mostly consumables like *potion of healing*, and the ones in *Xanathar's* that are permanent like this are for the most part cute or cosmetic in effect and weaker than your item, so I think Common would be too low. Rarity also reflects actual rarity, not just power, and this seems so specialized for wizards and their ilk, that it would be weird if it had wide availability.

The closest item I can find that adds damage to a spell is the *Outer Essence Shard (evil)*, which also requires attunement and allows sorcerers to add 3d6 necrotic to a spell they used metamagic on for one target. That one is rare, even more esoteric and limited to rare users. It is more powerful in working on any spell, and in adding 1.5 times more damage of a less resisted type (burning hands due to its small area can be expected to hit 2 targets, *DMG*, p. 249)

Practically all other items add damage to an attack instead, and that allows for unlimited reuse, which again is more powerful. For example, a *flame tongue* adds 2d6 to any attack and would be Rare. These more powerful items being Rare also point at Uncommon for yours.

Comment: +1, I agree, but is there any known analog for the "add 1d6 damage if you cast this spell" feature?

Comment: @DanB I know of no direct such analog (doesn't mean it doesn't exist, there are a lot of books by now) but added the closest analog I found.